# What is the ideal datatype to be used to store IP address in rails postgresql app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ip-address

I have a requirement where I need to store an IP address in the table on a rails app. The format could be of IPv4 or IPv6. Currently I thought of storing them as 'strings'. But is this a good approach. Could there be a better alternative here that could accomodate both?

Answer (score 4):

The appropriate PostgreSQL data type is clearly [`inet`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-INET).

While `inet` can also represent a subnet, it is also the appropriate type for a single IP address:

> The input format for this type is `address/y` where `address` is an IPv4 or IPv6 address and `y` is the number of bits in the netmask. If the `/y` portion is omitted, the netmask is taken to be 32 for IPv4 or 128 for IPv6, so the value represents just a single host.

Comment: I did a bit of read about that, my really confused between Inet and cidr type

Comment: @MaheshMesta: From the manual: The essential difference between inet and cidr data types is that inet accepts values with nonzero bits to the right of the netmask, whereas cidr does not. For example, 192.168.0.1/24 is valid for inet but not for cidr.

Comment: I added a quote to address the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

`string` works as well.

```rb
# Migration
t.string   :current_sign_in_ip

# Controller
user.current_sign_in_ip = request.remote_ip
```